# How to Fix "django channels", Failed to build cryptography?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-channels

I try to install Django channels and I get this error how to fix it?

```
  =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
  If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
  successfully install cryptography:
  1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
     users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
  2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
     instructions for your platform.
  3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
     https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
  4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
     https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
  5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
     set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
  =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
  
  error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Have you gone through all five steps?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading pip worked for me.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```